# How to make fonts available to the LaTeX interpreter in Matlab R2013a?

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex

It is possible to embed LaTeX-formatted text and equations into Matlab plots by setting the `text` property 'Interpreter' to the value 'latex', e.g.

```
text(0.1, 0.5, 'Einstein: $E = m c^2$', ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 32)
```

These equations appear on screen as well as in illustrations exported to eps files.

Through the appropriate LaTeX commands, it is also possible to change the font from the default Computer Modern Serif to e.g. Computer Modern Typewriter

```
text(0.1, 0.5, '\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont Einstein: $E = m c^2$', ...
    'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 32)
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to insert additional fonts into the Matlab installation, such that these fonts become available for use with 'Interpreter' 'latex', for rendering on screen as well as producing eps files? And if yes, how?

#### Background

(All paths relative to the Matlab installation, `/opt/MATLAB/R2013a` on my Linux system.)

Matlab includes a customized version of the (La)TeX interpreter. It is called via a frontend m-file called `tex.m` in `toolbox/matlab/graphics` which takes LaTeX code as an argument and returns dvi data within its output argument. The customized LaTeX installation is found in `sys/tex` and includes TeX font metric files under `sys/tex/tfm`.

I do not have any information on the parts of Matlab that render this dvi. However, font data for rendering are found under `sys/fonts/ttf` and `sys/fonts/type1`.

Making additional fonts usable therefore consists of two parts: Making it available for the LaTeX interpreter, and making it available for the rendering function. The first part can be tackled by manipulating `tex.m`, such that it generates the dvi through an independent regular installation of LaTeX, and installing the font to this LaTeX in the usual way (e.g. font packages). See [undocumentedmatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-latex-interface/#comment-209656).

The second part of the question is therefore the crucial one: How to insert additional fonts into `sys/fonts/ttf` and `sys/fonts/type1` such that they become usable by the dvi renderer component of Matlab.

#### Concrete case

I tried to concretely solve the second problem for a special case: The Computer Modern Sans font is included in the Matlab-LaTeX installation through `tex/tfm/cmss10.tfm`, but the corresponding ttf and pfb-files are missing from `sys/fonts` such that it does not get rendered.

Matlab's collection of ttf-files does not appear to have some kind of inventory. I therefore simply copied the file `cmss10.ttf` from an installation of matplotlib to `sys/fonts/ttf/cm/mwa_cmss10.ttf`, following the file and folder naming conventions of the other files present. This procedure was reported to be working on [Alec's Web Log](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2775) for Matlab 2011b on Max OS X, but on my system it has no effect, neither for screen display nor eps export.

Matlab's collection of type1 fonts has a complex inventory, distributed over files `fonts.dir`, `fonts.scale`, `encodings.dir` and a folder `encodings` full of enc-files. Again I found cmss10.pfb, this time from a TeXlive installation, renamed and copied it, and made entries in the inventory files following the example of the other fonts listed. Again, this procedure has no effect at all.

Does anyone know more about how Matlab uses ttf and pfb-files, and can give me a hint on how to make the cmss10-files accessible to Matlab rendering? Or does anyone have a suggestion how to debug this and find out more about the [inner workings](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/330973) of Matlab's LaTeX support?

Comment: In regards to the OS X blog Matlab [Solution 1-1432GA](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-1432GA/index.html?product=ML) might be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

I invested hours of further research into my question, and came up with some interesting new insights, but no real solution. Still, I'm posting my results here in order for others who might investigate this to start from. I post it as an "answer" not make my already long question even longer.

## Comparison between Matlab's old (R2010a) and current (R2013a) `tex` and `fonts` infrastructure

For the standard font Computer Modern Roman, the old infrastructure contains

```
sys/tex/tfm/cmr10.tfm
sys/fonts/ttf/cm/cmr10.ttf
sys/fonts/type1/cm/cmr10.pfb
sys/fonts/type1/cm/cmr10.pfm
```

and the current

```
sys/tex/tfm/cmr10.tfm
sys/fonts/ttf/cm/mwa_cmr10.ttf
sys/fonts/ttf/cm/mwb_cmr10.ttf
sys/fonts/type1/cm/mwa_cmr10.pfb
sys/fonts/type1/cm/mwb_cmr10.pfb
```

The TeX font metric files are identical. The truetype and type1 files appear to contain the same glyph data, but have been split into files containing latin (mwa) and greek characters (mwb). The pfm file has simply disappeared.The old type1 files have a copyright notice 1997 by the AMS, the new ones 2011 by the MW.

*This indicates that in order to make Computer Modern Sans from an old Matlab work in current Matlab, it might be sufficient to copy `cmss10.ttf` and `cmss10.pfb` to `mwa_cmss10.ttf` and `mwa_cmss10.pfb`, since the tfm file is still present (see question).*

## Which files are used in R2013a?

The additional dir and enc files in `sys/fonts/type1` appear not to be used, because deleting them leaves screen rendering and eps generation fully functional.

I suspected that the ttf files are used for screen rendering and the pfb files for inclusion in generated eps files. The former appears not to be the case, because deleting all ttf files leaves screen rendering and eps generation fully functional, too. Matlab does complain, however, if the folder `sys/fonts/ttf/cm` does not exist!

*This indicates that a) it's not necessary to bother with modifying the dir and enc files, and b) it's not necessary to copy the ttf file.*

## Is inserting new pfb files enough?

After `cmss10.pfb` from an old Matlab is copied to `sys/fonts/type1/cm/mwa_cmss10.pfb`, using Computer Modern Sans in an equation still makes Matlab warn that "cmss10 is not supported", and the screen rendering is not correct. Moreover, a generated eps file does not render correctly.

However, the generated eps file does include the contents of `mwa_cmss10.pfb` and the reason it doesn't work is that the included pfb file defines a font named "CMSS10", while the eps refers to a font named "mwa_cmss10". Instead of @Daniel E. Shub's solution to change the references in the eps, one can edit the file `mwa_cmss10.pfb` and change its `\FontName` to "mwa_cmss10". This might be done with a simple text editor applied to the pfb. However, the better way is to disassemble the pfb file to PostScript using `t1disasm`, change the PostScript, and then reassemble using `t1asm`. These tools are contained in the [t1utils](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/t1utils) package on CTAN.

The resulting eps does still not work properly though: Characters are not correctly positioned, especially for larger font sizes.

*This indicates that the presence of the pfb file alone does not provide Matlab with the correct font metrics, and that the dvi file generated by Matlab's LaTeX does not explicitly position characters but relies on the renderer having those metrics.*

See [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139497/dvi-with-explicit-positioning-of-each-character) for a question concerning a workaround for the second point.

## Does "hacking" existing fonts work?

Daniel E. Shub proposed in his answer not to add fonts, but to overwrite those existing in the Matlab installation. There are two problems with this:

– The correct font metrics are still not available to Matlab. Overwriting a font therefore only works, and only approximately, if the metrics of the original font and those of the new one are similar.

Example:
[image]

– Screen rendering only works in some cases. For me, overwriting mwa_cmr10 with a patched cmss10 and using `\rm` did lead to Computer Modern Sans being rendered to screen and in the eps file, albeit with slightly wrong positioning. However, overwriting mwa_cmtt10 and using `\tt` did not lead to Computer Modern Sans being rendered on screen; instead, Computer Modern Typewriter was rendered.

*This implies a) that there is another independent source of font metrics for Matlab's renderer. As far as I can tell, they come from none of the files under `sys/tex` or `sys/fonts`. b) Font outlines are only in some cases read from the pfb files in `sys/fonts/type1/cm`.*

## Conclusion

The inner workings of the dvi renderer in recent Matlab therefore remain mysterious. Possible candidates where the missing information may be hidden are `toolbox/matlab/graphics/hardcopy.p` and / or `com/mathworks/hg/uij/TextRasterizer.class` in `java/jar/hg.jar`.

I'll cease my investigations for the time being (and going to have a look at psfrag ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure the `dvi` file has the wrong metrics because you didn't change the `tfm` file. Have you tried renaming cmms10.tfm to be cmr10.tfm? My guess is the magic/problem is related to the change in name from `cmr10.tfm` to `mwa_cmr10.pfb`

Comment: You are right that in order for the "hacking" solution to work correctly, one has to modify cmr10.tfm, too. But I just did that (including patching the font name within the tfm-file), and the metrics still come out wrong. I still believe there must be another independent source of font metrics that the Matlab renderer uses.

Answer (score 3):

I made the comment on [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-latex-interface/#comment-209656) that you refer to. Apparently, I grossly underestimated the difficulty of making the Matlab DVI viewer work with fonts. I have included a non-working solution in the hope that someone can understand the warning it generates. I also have a working solution that is a pretty big hack. I am using Matlab R2013a and TexLive 2013 on Linux. I am not sure what will happen on Mac or Windows.

**Non working solution**

My first approach was to overload the Matlab `tex.m` function so I can easily do things in LaTeX and only have to worry about the `dvi` file

```
function [dviout,errout,auxout] = tex(varargin)
    fid = fopen('matlab.dvi');
    dviout = fread(fid, 'uint8');
    dviout = uint8(dviout);
    fclose(fid);
    errout = [];
    auxout = [];
end
```

I then created `matlab.dvi` by processing

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0in}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{myfont}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{myfont}{m}{n}{<-> [1.2] AuriocusKalligraphicus}{}
\begin{document}%
\setbox0=\hbox{\usefont{T1}{myfont}{m}{n}Some text with a distinct font $\alpha$}%
\copy0\special{bounds: \the\wd0 \the\ht0 \the\dp0}%
\end{document}%
```

I then copied the TexLive font to Matlab

```
# cp $TEXLIVEROOT/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/AuriocusKalligraphicus.pfb $MATLABROOT/sys/fonts/AuriocusKalligraphicus.pfb
```

I get the "expected" warnings from

```
>> text(0.0, 0.5, 'DOES NOT MATTER', 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX', 'FontSize', 20)
Warning: Font AuriocusKalligraphicus10 is not supported. 
Warning: Font AuriocusKalligraphicus10 is not supported.
```

If I try and export the figure (with the missing fonts) to a `pdf` file via `alt+f` `alt+r` I get a whole bunch of warnings including the potentially useful

> Warning: Missing
>   /usr/local/matlab/R2013a/sys/fonts/type1/cm/mwa_auriocuskalligraphicus10.pfb

**Working hack solutiuon**

After becoming feed up with not knowing what to call the `pfb` files, I decided to overwrite one that already works (cmr10).

At the CLI

```
# cp $MATLABROOT/sys/fonts/mwa_cmr10.pfb $MATLABROOT/sys/fonts/mwa_cmr10.pfb.bak
# cp $TEXLIVEROOT/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/AuriocusKalligraphicus.pfb $MATLABROOT/sys/fonts/mwa_cmr10.pfb
```

and at the Matlab prompt

```
>> text(0.0, 0.5, 'Some text with a distinct font $\alpha$', 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX', 'FontSize', 20)
```

gives me

[image: Matlab figure].

In order to export the figure to an `eps` with the fonts you need to replace all the instances of `/mwa_cmr10` with `/AuriocusKalligraphicus` in the `eps` file. Presumably this is because this solution is a hack. Ideally I should not only replace the `pfb` file, but also the `fd` and `tfm` files. There are probably enough `pfb` fonts available to allow you to create most figures.

Comment: Hi Daniel, interesting material. I have never gotten as far as that warning about a missing pfb file. Have you tried putting your font into a file `mwa_auriocuskalligraphicus10.pfb` in the folder `cm`?

Comment: @A.Donda yes, and it makes the warning go away, but it is not enough. I don't think you can just rename font files.

Comment: Daniel, I managed to find out some more things, but it didn't lead to a solution. See my "answer".

Answer (score 0):

This is a very crude solution, but you may edit the resulting .eps file using a text editor and get the desired fonts. For example you can replace following:

> %%IncludeResource: font mwa_cmr10 /mwa_cmr10 /WindowsLatin1Encoding
>   120 FMSR

with following:

> %%IncludeResource: font Helvetica /Helvetica /WindowsLatin1Encoding
>   120 FMSR

You may even write a simple script which would open the resulting .eps file and replace any font with anyone you desire. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes that the font metrics match between the font used by Matlab and the one it is replaced by, doesn't it? Otherwise the result will likely look like the image in my answer.

Comment: If you need special characters like dot over a letter, then yes changing the font to another one like Helvetica will not result in what you want. However, in your example of E = mc^2, you may change all of the characters to Helvetica.

In my case, I'm trying to write a paper that I'll submit to an Elsevier journal. In their website, they say that the font type should be restricted to their list of five fonts (including Helvetica) **where possible**. For special characters it is simply not possible and I'll leave them like that. For the rest, I applied the trick I mentioned.