# MatLab Eps Print Webdings interpreter

Tags: matlab, export, eps

So recently I decided to not use the standard markers that Matlab provides and use my own via: a set of fonts including Webdings or WingDings. I make a standard scatter plot, and plot the text (in wingdings), using the text command, over the locations of the markers.

When I save these plots as png files, they print perfectly. They also appear perfectly on my screen after plotting.

However when I save these plots as eps files, the webdings are turning into their original letters 'l' or 'w'. It also looks like it's plotting them in a Courier font, but my default is Helvetica. 

I've read through this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435848/how-to-make-fonts-available-to-the-latex-interpreter-in-matlab-r2013a), but my question differs in that he is looking to use Latex as the interpreter and to include fonts, whereas I don't want to use Latex as the interpreter. However, it seems like my default interpreter (not sure what that is), isn't doing the job when converting to EPS.

Example:

```
imageR='w'
text(xf2,yf2,imageR,'fontName',font,'FontSize',fontR,'HorizontalAl','left','color','w')
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out....took me way too long.
Ghostscript / Postscript only export with  a [few fonts](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/techdoc/printing/output7.html#18305) when you are exporting eps files. 
This [link](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/techdoc/printing/exporti5.html#74036) was incredibly helpful.

I just switched from wingdings/webdings to ZapfDinbats...Practically the same thing...